# Rails 5.1/Devise 4.4 - Testing: undefined method `setup' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I am running into a "undefined method `setup' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)" when testing with Rails. I am getting this error when running any of my tests.

I am using the test setup from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and in addition have included Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers (for integration tests) and Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers (for controller tests) in my test files.

This is the error I am getting:
.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise4.4.3/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:30:in `block in <module:ControllerHelpers>': undefined method`setup' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)

This is the line from the controller_helpers file the error refers to:

```
module Devise
   module Test

      module ControllerHelpers
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
           setup :setup_controller_for_warden, :warden
        end
         .
         .
         .
```

These are my test gems:

```
group :test do
   gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
   gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
   gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
   gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end
```

This is my test_helper.rb file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :all 
end
```

This is one of my tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

 setup do
    @user = users(:one)
 end

 test "should get index" do
    get users_url
    assert_response :success
 end

 test "should get new" do
   get new_user_url
   assert_response :success
 end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue ? I am curious because I might have run into something very similar.